# Oracle 12c - Using Dynamic SQL in a REST call

Tags: json, oracle, rest, dynamic-sql

In Oracle 12c, and using APEX (but I don't know if that is relevant)... I am wanting to create a generic REST call, where I can pass in the SQL statement (Select only) and have a dataset returned via JSON.  This dataset may have a few column or many....

I am using a sys_refCursor, and can get a static SQL statement to work, but I cannot get it to work using a DYNAMIC SQL statement.  For now, I am just trying to put the statement into a variable.  Once this is working, I will pass the SQL statement into the REST call as opposed to having it hardcoded into a variable.  The code below works as written, but what I am wanting is to use the 2 commented lines INSTEAD of hard coding the 'open c for...' line.  What am I doing wrong?

```
DECLARE
c sys_refcursor;
sql_stmt  VARCHAR2(200);

BEGIN

apex_json.open_object;
open c for select * from tabs where rownum < 5;

--sql_stmt := 'open c for select * from tabs where rownum < 5';
--EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;

apex_json.write('rows', c);
apex_json.close_all;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Obvious huge warnings on the potential of SQL Injection. Even with select only it could call a function.***

Here's what I did to demo what you are talking about.

1. Create this function where ***a metric ton of sanitizing code*** should go to prevent SQL Injection.

> ```
> create or replace function execsql(p_sql varchar2) 
>     return SYS_REFCURSOR
> as
>   TYPE curtype IS REF CURSOR;
>   src_cur  curtype;
> begin
>  open src_cur for p_sql; 
>  return src_cur;
> end;
> /
> ```

2. Create this REST API in ORDS / APEX

> select execsql(:sql) mycursor from dual

[image]

The results:

```
klrice$ http "xxxxxx/sqlplus/select?select+*+from+dual"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: application/json


{
    "items": [
        {
            "mycursor": [
                {
                    "dummy": "X"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "next": {
        "$ref": "xxxxx/sqlplus/select?select+*+from+dual&page=1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Understood about the security warnings.  This is just a starting point.